# How to root a Lenovo A526 mobile

Tags: applications, rooting, root-access, lenovo

I tried to root a Lenovo A526 mobile using "Kingo" and "root genius". But they are unable to root this device.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but I used kingroot to root my tablet some 3 months earlier after which I removed it because I thought it would be dangerous. But It rooted...
So You Answer Should Be:-
I don't know but KingRoot roots easily and on mobile or tablet without pc

Answer (score -1):

I'm even using A526 but in the latest version of root genius you will be able to root your phone.

Comment: Could you explain the process?

Comment: … and include where to find that genie?

Comment: http://androidxda.com/download-root-genius